# How do you abbreviate "fecha de nacimiento" in Spanish?

Tags: abreviaturas

How do you abbreviate "fecha de nacimiento" in Spanish?

Comment: Do you want an abbreviation for a form?

Comment: Hello, Cristian, and welcome to [Spanish Language](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/). In order to formulate a good question, maybe you'd want to elaborate a bit more. For instance, you may explain that in English is common to use the initials DOB for _Date of Birth_, then ask if there is something similar in Spanish, and finally tell us what you have researched so far. Then we will be happy to upvote your question.

Comment: There is not an "official" abbreviation for "fecha de nacimiento". But, as explained in the [Apéndice 2: Lista de abreviaturas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html), "cualquier usuario de la lengua puede crear cuantas abreviaturas considere oportunas, siempre que lo haga de acuerdo con las [reglas de formación de este tipo de abreviaciones](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz)".

Answer (score 3):

It isn't common but you might use *Fec. Nac.*, alternatively *Nacido/da el:*.